# How to search amazon products using product advertising api in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I am following [this github](https://github.com/making/aws-apa) implementation to get amazon products.

I gave a sample request using this snippet :

```
AwsApaRequester requester = new AwsApaRequesterImpl(); 
String asin = "489471499X"; 
ItemLookupRequest request = new ItemLookupRequest(); 
request.setIdType("ASIN"); request.getItemId().add(asin); 
request.getResponseGroup().add("Small"); 
ItemLookupResponse response = requester.itemLookup(request);
```

It gives Bad request `400 error @ AwsApaRequesterImpl.class` on line number 166 .
But I am giving sample request as per the github Readme.MD , am I missing something?

Comment: ` AwsApaRequester requester = new AwsApaRequesterImpl();
     String asin = "489471499X";
     ItemLookupRequest request = new ItemLookupRequest();
     request.setIdType("ASIN");
     request.getItemId().add(asin);
     request.getResponseGroup().add("Small");
     ItemLookupResponse response = requester.itemLookup(request);`

Comment: I am unable to add code to question, adding to the above comment , please edit if someone can

Comment: I edited it, we have to wait until it is peer reviewed